# How to restore pom.xml file after deleting it in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

In Eclipse, I was troubleshooting errors in my pom.xml file and then I deleted it. Is there any way to create a new one without creating a new project?

Comment: Right-click the project folder and choose _New > File_, type `pom.xml` and copy the contents from wherever you want. Or restore your deleted one by right-clicking the project folder and choosing _Restore from Local History..._

Answer (score 1):

If you use git, you can easily restore it. In where was the "pom.xml" file, execute below command:

```
git checkout pom.xml
```